# filter a list of dictionarys by key and values & add to the dictionary by specific key

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I want to filter a list of dictionarys by key "IP" and value of that key.
This is my list for example.

**

```
a=[{'IP': '192.168.0.5', 'Temp1': ['58.0']}, 
   {'IP': '192.168.0.6', 'Temp1': ['59.1']}, 
   {'IP': '192.168.0.5', 'Temp2': ['59.1']}, 
   {'IP': '192.168.0.6', 'Temp2': ['60.7']}]
```

**

Is it possible to make it look like this?
I want to filter by "IP" so it looks like this:

**

```
filtered=[{'IP': '192.168.0.5', 'Temp1': ['58.0'],'Temp2': ['59.1']}, 
          {'IP': '192.168.0.6', 'Temp1': ['59.1'],'Temp2': ['60.7']}]
```

**

But I dont know how to exactly do it, can somebody please explain it to me?

Comment: I know there are a lot of posts about similar things like this, but I didnt really find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
        a=[{'IP': '192.168.0.5', 'Temp1': ['58.0']}, 
           {'IP': '192.168.0.6', 'Temp1': ['59.1']}, 
           {'IP': '192.168.0.5', 'Temp2': ['59.1']}, 
           {'IP': '192.168.0.6', 'Temp2': ['60.7']}]        
        filtered=[{'IP': '192.168.0.5', 'Temp1': ['58.0'],'Temp2': ['59.1']}, 
                  {'IP': '192.168.0.6', 'Temp1': ['59.1'],'Temp2': ['60.7']}]        
        
        import collections
        b = collections.defaultdict(dict)
        for d in a:
            for k, v in d.items():
                b[d['IP']][k] = v
        c = list(b.values())
        print(c)
```

Output is:

```
[{'IP': '192.168.0.5', 'Temp1': ['58.0'], 'Temp2': ['59.1']}, {'IP': '192.168.0.6', 'Temp1': ['59.1'], 'Temp2': ['60.7']}]
```

Comment: I left it exactly like you did it and it says - name 'defaultdict' is not defined, but if I replace: b ={}, it says key error for me. Am I missing something? Iam sorry Iam new guy to this.

Comment: no need for `[v for v in b.values()]` just use `list(b.values())`

Comment: `from collections import defaultdict` will make this one work.

Comment: @JKK `from collections import defaultdict`

Comment: @Samwise same time

Comment: @Jab, good catch - updated answer to simplify.

Comment: @JKK please see updated answer which imports `collections` module and uses `collections.defaultdict`. The reason to use `defaultdict` instead of the built-in `dict` datatype (or `{}` as you have tried) is as a convenience to automatically add a value for a key not yet in the dictionary, which saves on checking this explicitly in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method where we build the dict of `IP: dict` via a comprehension before doing the `update` loop:

```
>>> a=[{'IP': '192.168.0.5', 'Temp1': ['58.0']},
...    {'IP': '192.168.0.6', 'Temp1': ['59.1']},
...    {'IP': '192.168.0.5', 'Temp2': ['59.1']},
...    {'IP': '192.168.0.6', 'Temp2': ['60.7']}]
>>> by_ip = {ip: {'IP': ip} for ip in {d['IP'] for d in a}}
>>> for d in a:
...     by_ip[d['IP']].update(d)
...
>>> filtered = list(by_ip.values())
>>> filtered
[{'IP': '192.168.0.5', 'Temp1': ['58.0'], 'Temp2': ['59.1']}, {'IP': '192.168.0.6', 'Temp1': ['59.1'], 'Temp2': ['60.7']}]
```

And here's a method where we can do it in one crazy nested comprehension via `functools.reduce`:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> filtered = [reduce(dict.__or__, (d for d in a if d['IP'] == ip), {'IP': ip}) for ip in {d['IP'] for d in a}]
>>> filtered
[{'IP': '192.168.0.5', 'Temp1': ['58.0'], 'Temp2': ['59.1']}, {'IP': '192.168.0.6', 'Temp1': ['59.1'], 'Temp2': ['60.7']}]
```

Comment: I was going to post "*one crazy nested comprehension*" based on `collections.ChainMap()` but this seems to cover the "*one crazy nested comprehension*" nicely.